# import multiple csv from folder into a dataframe in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, pyserial

I was trying to import 15 different csv into a data frame. 
Installed pyserial and it still shows "cannot import name serial"
Also tried to

```
"try:
    import serial  # Python2
except ImportError:
    from serial3 import *  # Python3"
```

and still not able to run it. 
Here is my code:

```
from serial import serial 
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
allfiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
for file_ in allfiles:
    df1 = pd.read.csv(file_, index_col=None)
    list_.append(df1)
frame = pd.concat(list_)

print frame

ImportError: cannot import name serial
```

Thanks everyone in advance !

Comment: There are no linkage between them. It might if that is a API or port settings.

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
from serial import serial
```

to:

```
from serial import Serial
                   ^
                   Capital S
```

you also need to do this

```
     pd.read.csv(file_, index_col=None)
            ^
     pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None)
```

if you haven' imported pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: It shows"'module' object has no attribute 'read'", after capitalized it.

Comment: The code is loading now, but with All NaN on all columns

             0  1  1502  1589  1629  1645  1665  1702  1766  1781  ...   2282  \
0            1  1  1667   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
1            2  1  1611   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
2            3  1  1601   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN

Comment: Can your post ur input csv file content?

Comment: Pandas is imported as pd.